# Incompatibility between AMS classes and Kp-fonts package (extended versions of \widetilde and \widehat)

Tags: math-mode, amsart, amsbook, kpfonts

The [kpfonts](https://ctan.org/pkg/kpfonts) package extends the `\widetilde` and `\widehat` commands (see §3.5 in the package documentation). Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
\[\widetilde{bigtilde} \quad \widehat{bighat}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: widetilde and widehat with article class]

Now this breaks down when we use this package with the AMS classes ([amsart](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsart), [amsbook](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsbook)). Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
\[\widetilde{bigtilde} \quad \widehat{bighat}\]
\end{document}
```

[image: widetilde and widehat with amsart class]

I looked into the amsart.tex file to find the cause of this, unsuccessfully... If someone with better knowledge of these classes has an explanation I would be very interested! (Actually I am primarily interested in the smfart and smfbook from the [smflatex](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/smflatex) bundle, but these are based on the AMS classes.)

Comment: Do you have the option to compile your document with LuaLaTeX? If so, you could employ the `kpfonts-otf` package instead of the "standard" `kpfonts` package. With the former package loaded, I can't detect a difference in output depending on whether the `article` or the `amsart` document class is in use.

Comment: Thanks. I never used LuaLaTeX, and I am not prepared to change for it. Do you get the correct `\widetilde` and `\widehat` with LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Yes, as long as the `kpfonts-otf` package is loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `amsart` loads `amsfonts`, which changes the definition of the wide accents.

Use the `noamsfonts` option that disable loading the package, which is not needed anyway.

```
\documentclass[noamsfonts]{amsart}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\begin{document}
\[\widetilde{bigtilde} \quad \widehat{bighat}\]
\end{document}
```

You'll have to live with an annoying warning about `\dh`, though.

[image]

Comment: Great, thank you! I can live the warning :)